# CSS Selector :nth-child(odd|even) only on subset of elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking for a CSS selector that counts every other child of its parent, but *excluding* certain elements from the counting. I see that the examples I came up with don't *select* the row marked as `.ignore`, but they still count them.

Is there a CSS-way to select and count only the `.normal` elements?

```css
/* trying to exclude .ignore from the set doesn't work */
tr:not(.ignore):nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

/* neither does filtering by .normal before applying nth-child */
tr.normal:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="normal"><td>text</td></tr>
    <tr class="normal"><td>text to be highlighted</td></tr>
    <tr class="normal"><td>text</td></tr>
    <tr class="ignore"><td>don't count this row</td></tr>
    <tr class="normal"><td>text to be highlighted</td></tr>
    <tr class="normal"><td>text</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Swap your :not, `tr:nth-child(even):not(.ignore)`

Comment: Swapping doesn't work either. I see my question is an exact duplicate. Seems there is no way w/o javascript.

Comment: Oh right, didn't see you wanted it to have it basically re-start the even selector after a .ignore though I bet if we saw the real structure it could still be done without js.